# Solving equation with Wiener process

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I want to show that if $E(f(X_{t}))=E(f(W_{t})e^{\lambda W_{t}-0.5*\lambda^2*t})$, where $W_{t}$ is a Wiener Process, then $X_{t}\sim N(\lambda t,t)$. Does anyone have a clue how to solve this problem?

Comment: Sure--If $E(f(X_t))=E(f(W_t)g(t,W_t))$ for every $f$, then $$E(f(X_t))=\int_\mathbb R f(x)g(t,x)p_t(x)dx,$$ for every $f$, where $p_t$ denotes the PDF of $W_t$, hence the PDF of $X_t$ is $q_t$, where $$q_t(x)=g(t,x)p_t(x).$$ In your case, $p_t$ is the PDF of $N(0,t)$ and $g(t,x)=\exp(\lambda x-\lambda^2t/2)$ hence...

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^{+}$ be $x \mapsto e^{\theta x}$. Then, since $W_t\sim N(0,t)$, the given relationship implies $\mathbb E[e^{\theta X_t}] = \mathbb E [e^{(\theta + \lambda) W_t}] e^{-\frac{1}{2} \lambda^2 t} = e^{\frac{1}{2}\theta^2 t + \theta \lambda t}$; the moment generating function for a random variable distributed as $N(\lambda t, t)$.